# how to create a linked list inside a linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

I want to create a main list and each of the main list element has another list.

here is what i did

```
    typedef struct smallList
    {   char data;
        struct smallList *next;  

     } small;

    typedef struct bigList
    {
        int count;
        char data;
        struct bigList *next;
        struct smallList *head;
     } big;
```

but how do I access the small list data from the big list and add stuff to the small list.
any help much appreciated. thanks....

Comment: Hey dawg, I heard you liked linked lists, so we created a linked list inside a linked list so you can enjoy a linked list while you iterate though another linked list.

Comment: This sounds like the question from yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094665/inserting-a-word-in-a-doubly-linked-list-and-checking-incrementing-frequency#comment21238487_15094665) where a poster needed to make a linked lists where each item held another linked list for a class assignment. That didn't get an answer posted at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if we assume that this structure is already populated, we could do:

```
struct smallList *smallElem = NULL;
struct bigList *bigElem = NULL;

for (bigElem = your_big_list(); bigElem != NULL; bigElem = bigElem->next) {
    // Do something with bigElem.

    for (smallElem = bigElem->head; smallElem != NULL; smallElem = smallElem->next) {
        // Do something with the smallElem.
        // Note that we can still reference bigElem here as well.
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help. does "your_big_list()" returns the address of the first element(or any element) in big List.

Comment: @user1476263: I would likely use this with the first element of the list, but it will iterate starting at any given element through the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

If `p` points to a bigList:

- `bigList -> head` is the small list that bigList points.
- `(bigList -> head).data` is the character the smallList contains.
- `(bigList -> next -> head)` is second smallList in bigList.
- `(bigList > head -> next)` is the second element in bigList's first smallList.

After getting a pointer to the structure you want to modify, everything else is the same.